# Add/Subtract UTC Time to Datetime 'Time' column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-processing

I have a sample dataframe as given below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'InsertedDate':['2022-01-21 20:13:19.000000', '2022-01-21 20:20:24.000000', '2022-02- 
         02 16:01:49.000000', '2022-02-09 15:01:31.000000'],
        'UTCOffset': ['-05:00','+02:00','-04:00','+06:00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['InsertedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['InsertedDate'])
df
```

The 'InsertedDate' is a datetime column wheres the 'UTCOffset' is a string column.
I want to add the Offset time to the 'Inserteddate' column and display the final result in a new column as a 'datetime' column.
It should look something like this image shown below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta` for the offset and add with time.

```py
# to_timedelta needs to have [+-]HH:MM:SS format, so adding :00 to fill :SS part.
df['UTCOffset'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.UTCOffset + ':00')
df['CorrectTime'] = df.InsertedDate + df.UTCOffset
```